# \paragraphfootnotes with text colour

Tags: color, page-breaking, memoir, footnotes

I am having some trouble with my footnotes becoming coloured in certain situations. In particular, I am wanting to use `memoir`'s `\paragraphfootnotes`, but all the footnotes for a page become coloured if coloured text crosses a page boundary. I am using pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\paragraphfootnotes

\begin{document}

This\footnote{a footnote} is\footnote{another footnote} \textcolor{red}{some red
\newpage text} with a page break.

\end{document}
```

If I don't use `\paragraphfootnotes` (i.e. if I just use `\plainfootnotes`) then everything works properly, but that is not an option when I sometimes have 50+ very short footnotes on a single page. Is there some colour-resetting code missing from `memoir`'s implementation of `\paragraphfootnotes`? How can I fix this?

Note: This problem also appears if I use `\twocolumnfootnotes`.

Comment: Noted, though I have no idea what the problem is

Answer (score 5):

This can be fixed by loading the [`bigfoot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package. Quoting from [*The `bigfoot` bundle for critical editions*](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-0/kastrup-bigfoot.pdf), p. 199--200:

> So what are the features that `bigfoot` provides?
>
> [...]
>
> - When footnotes are broken across pages, the color stack is maintained
>     properly. Color is handled in LaTeX with the help of specials that
>     switch the color (and, in the case of `dvips`, restoring it afterwards
>     with the help of a color stack). Restarting the footnote on the next
>     page with the proper color is something that has never worked in
>     LaTeX. Now it simply does.

EDIT: `memoir`'s `\paragraphfoototes` must be replaced with `bigfoot`'s `\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}`, which will result in different spacing between footnotes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

\begin{document}

This\footnote{a footnote} is\footnote{another footnote} \textcolor{red}{some red
\newpage text} with a page break.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work. It ignores `\paragraphfootnotes` and other commands, so it's actually just like using `\plainfootnotes` from memoir which already works fine.

Comment: From the very minimal documentation, I tried using `\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}[alph]` but that choked because I sometimes have more than 26 footnotes per page. I was then able to fix this with `\renewcommand*{\thefootnotedefault}{\textbf{\textrm{\alphalph{\value{footnotedefault}}}}}` and `\MakePerPage{footnotedefault}` but the footnote spacing within the paragraph footnote blocks is all wrong (it will often just put one footnote when previously 3 would have been). Maybe I just need one or two other commands, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @codebeard I updated my answer. The spacing seems to be different, but not "all wrong" with `bigfoot`. Can you give an example with clearly improper spacing (maybe in a follow-up question, as this would be a different issue from wrong colouring)?

Comment: You're right it's not “all wrong” per se, but it's significantly different. Namely, the indentation is large and the `para*` option from `manyfoot` doesn't seem to go through properly (which is supposed to stop the indentation). `\SetFootnoteHook{}` doesn't seem to help either.

The main issue, though, is that footnotes will *start* on a new line if there's not enough space for them to *finish* on the previous line. This wastes a lot of space and is nothing like memoir's paragraph footnotes.

Comment: This is for a volunteer project to typeset a new Bible translation. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/YP3J9.png) of what I had with `\paragraphfootnotes`:
The full source is publicly available at https://github.com/kieranclancy/isv_tex/ and you can see the footnote options I was trying to use [here](https://github.com/kieranclancy/isv_tex/blob/master/isv.tex#L56).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly odd workaround

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \normalcolor\hrule width .4\columnwidth
  \kern 2.6\p@}
\makeatother
```

I added the `\normalcolor`. Think I'll add that to the next version.